# What is the difference between お風呂 and 銭湯?

Tags: meaning, words

I saw that the term お風呂 can refer to both and 銭湯 is apparently used for a public one. I see the term bath listed in Jisho. Would I take an お風呂 at a 銭湯?

Comment: You can figure this out but looking up "public bath" in your favourite dictionary and doing a google image search for お風呂

Comment: And for your new question: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%8A%AD%E6%B9%AF

Comment: I added the other term to the original question to clarify it.

Comment: `I saw that the term お風呂 can refer to both` <-- both って、何と何？ 「お風呂」と「銭湯」？

Comment: はいそうですね　お風呂の意味とか銭湯の意味が近いです

Comment: an ofuro can be taken at a sentou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `風呂` itself is generic: it can refer to a bathtub, a place for bathing, or the act/practice of bathing. In practice, it almost always refers to a bath at home, except for some set terms like 風呂屋 (bathhouse) or 露天風呂(open-air bath; can be private or shared). You can still say 風呂に入る (take a bath) even when not doing it at home (it can also mean "take a shower").

銭湯 is specifically a communal bath open to visitors for a fee (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sent%C5%8D)). Strictly speaking it is also a type of 風呂 (since it's used to bathe).

Then there is 温泉 (onsen) which is a bath that uses hot spring water, and is usually public/shared among multiple visitors, although private ones are possible too.

See also [Public Baths](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2074.html) by japan-guide.

Comment: Personal and public use is the key!